# How to synchronize the Business Hours and Holidays in Dynamics 365 using Data Export Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, data-export

I wanted to synchronize the business hours and holidays to Azure SQL using the data export service in Dynamics 365. I can't find the entities that I needed to synchronized, is it possible to do and if it is which entities should I synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for special entities that too very complex internal type entities, which is not available for enabling change tracking & thus Data Export service (DES) cannot replicate in Azure SQL. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/types-calendars)

Probably you can use the REST Web API endpoint `[organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/calendars` to pull these & store explicitly. I have not tried it, but did a simple browser test successfully. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/calendar?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Worst case, create them manually in SQL directly for usage. Instead of all the above complicated route.